# Layout Issue - Different In Chrome And Firefox

Tags: html, css

Unable to figure this out. Which style is correct based on the css? Should each 'lorem' line up in it's own row as it is shown in firefox? or split like in chrome? How can I fix it so both browsers look the same?

Here is what I have currently

```
    <body>
        <header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</header>
        <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</section>
        <article>article Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</article>
        <aside>aside Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</aside>
        <footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</footer>
    </body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nKHkg/

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
header {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}
section {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 100px;
}
article {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 20px;
}
footer {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

The above looks the same with Firefox

In Chrome, the article and aside is divided into two columns and looks uneven.

Comment: So ... what's the question?

Comment: Maybe....Why are the article and aside is divided?

Comment: I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what's wrong with the article and aside and then decided to view it in firefox and it looks different. Which is correct and how do I make the layout look the same on both browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you needed to do was apply good site architecture. When creating sections throughout the site you need to set your containers appropriately by using `margin`, `float`, `display`, and `clear:both`

See the difference now in your [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/nKHkg/4/)

Comment: yes, it clears the floats [clear](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)